# Variable declaration in function prototype and in block code : difference?

Tags: c, arrays, function-call

Why `int array[]` raise a compilation error in main but not in function prototype ?
Should it mean that it is better to always write `int * array` in function prototype ?

```
void myfoo (int array[]) { // No compilation error
;}

void myfoo1 (int *array1) { // No compilation error
;}

int main() {
    int array[]; // Compilation error
    int* array1; // No compilation error
}
```

Comment: The compiler in your main needs to know how much memory to allocate for your array on stack as it is save as a continuous block. allocating a int* allocates size of (pointer) on stack . Your function can get an address to an array, but you will not be able to know its size unless you send it as a variable to the function as well. when you send a var to a function by value- the int* makes room for an int pointer type only, not the hole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the reason an array declaration inside the block for `main` needs a size and the array declaration in the function parameter does not is that the declaration in `main` is **defining** an array, whereas the function parameter is merely **receiving** an array that something else defines.

So the definition in `main` needs a size because it must reserve storage for the array.

The function parameter is merely receiving an array, so it only needs to know where the array starts. It does not need to know the size. (That is, the compiler does not need to know the size in order to compile the code. The function may need to know the size in order to perform its intended purpose, but that is a matter for the programmer, not the compiler.)

Due to C rules, arrays can never actually be passed as function arguments. Whenever an array is given as a function parameter, the compiler automatically converts it to a pointer to its first element. Similarly, a function parameter can be a pointer but cannot actually be an array. When you declare a function parameter as an array, the compiler automatically adjust it to declare a pointer instead. So the function declaration `void myfoo(int array[])` is automatically adjusted to be `void myfoo(int *array)`.

The specific rule that requires the declaration in `main` to have a size is C 2018 6.7 7:

> If an identifier for an object is declared with no linkage, the type for the object shall be complete by the end of its declarator, or by the end of its init-declarator if it has an initializer;…

Comment: Is `void myfoo(int array[])`is automatically adjusted to `void myfoo(int *array )` or  `void myfoo(int (*array) )` ? See my last comment @Sourav,

Comment: @Stef1611: `void myfoo(int *array)` and `void myfoo(int (*array))` are the same thing.

Comment: In this case, I agree but I should have added a word like "strictly". I do not how to link a comment so I do a copy : I know that an array decays to a pointer but what bothers me is that you could use `array []` in prototype. Is void `myfoo (int array[])` strictly equivalent to `void myfoo (int *array)`? For example, you could write `myfoo (int array[][2])` and it runs but `myfoo (int *array[2])` compiles but does not run. You have to write myfoo `(int (*array)[2])`. Is it only a question of operator precedence or are there some hidden subtilities ?

Answer (score 4):

In your code, inside the function, writing `int array[];` for an array definition is a semantic error.

In this case, `array` is a variable with no linkage, (*"a block scope
identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`"*) and as per the spec:

> If an identifier for an object is declared with no linkage, the type for the object shall be
>   complete by the end of its declarator, [....]

An empty `[]` (with or without space(s) in between), does not make a valid construct for an array definition, as the size of the array remains unknown (Notice the lack of an explicit brace-enclosed list of initializer, too). Thus, your compiler complains, as the type is not complete and it has no idea of the total amount of memory to be reserved for that array variable.

On the other hand, for function parameters, an array type parameter actually decays to a pointer to the type, so, specifying the array size is not mandatory. Quoting chapter §6.7.6.3

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the
>   array type derivation. [...]

and

> If the function declarator is not part of a definition of that function, parameters may have
>   incomplete type and may use the `[*]` notation in their sequences of declarator specifiers
>   to specify variable length array types.

So, basically, a statement

```
 void myfoo (int array[])
```

is equivalent as

```
void myfoo (int *array)
```

so, this is accepted by compiler.

Comment: I agree with all the answers but why you could use `int array []` to declare a **POINTER** in the function prototype and not in a block of code.

Comment: @Stef1611 Because, as I mentioned, in case of a function argument, the array decays to a pointer, so the array size is optional. However, inside block of code, an array and a pointer are different types and they have different properties.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh. I know that an array decays to a pointer but what bothers me is that you could use `array []`in prototype. Is `void myfoo (int array[])` strictly equivalent to `void myfoo (int *array)`? For example, you could write `myfoo (int array[][2])` but `myfoo (int *array[2])` compiles but does not run. You have to write `myfoo (int (*array)[2])`. Is it only a question of operator precedence or are there some hidden subtilities ?

Comment: @Stef1611: `int array[][2]` is an array (of unknown size) of arrays of two `int`. Since it is an array, when it is a function parameter declaration, it is automatically adjusted to be a pointer to an array of two `int`, which is `int (*array)[2]`. If you wrote `int *array[2]`, that is different; that is an array of two pointers to `int`. Yes, it is just operator precedence here that is requiring the parentheses. `[]` bind more tightly than `*`, so, when changing an array `array[]` to a pointer, you need to add parentheses to keep them together, `(*array)`.

Comment: @Stef1611: Thus, you could also say `int array[]` becomes `int (*array)`. It is just that, in that case, there is no other operator included, so the parentheses do not happen to be needed. In `int array[][2]`, you need to use parentheses to keep the `*` with the `array`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, I updated the text to clear the context..better now?

Comment: @Eric. You tell me that `int *array[2]` is an array of two pointers to int. In a block of code, I agree. But in a prototype I thought that it was a pointer to a pointer of integer because int *array[2] is for me equivalent to int *array[].

Comment: @Stef1611 Nope, think it from the other point of view, You call the function as `func(arr);`, where `arr` is declared as `int arr[3][2];`, here, `arr` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array type `int [2]`. So, the receiver function parameter, `int func(int param[][2])` is the same as `int func(int (*param)[2])`, but `int func(int *param[2])` is not the same!!

Comment: @Stef1611 in other words, `int func(int *param[2])` and `int func(int (*param)[2])` is not the same. The former is an array of 2 `int *`s, whereas the later is a pointer to an array of type `int [2]`. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: @Stef1611 `is void myfoo (int array[]) strictly equivalent to void myfoo (int *array)?` - yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Stef1611: `int *array[2]` is an array of two pointers to `int`. That is how it is defined. When it is used as a declaration of an array parameter; it is *automatically adjusted* to be a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. You might think of it as “having a different meaning in a function declaration,” but, the way the rules in the C standard describe the situation is that the declaration **first** has its plain meaning, an array of two pointers to `int`, and **then** is adjusted to be a pointer. The end result may be the same, but I am describing how to understand the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you sir, appreciate your continuous engagement to level up the quality of the content.

Comment: I agree with @EricPostpischil : _"When it is used as a declaration of an array parameter; it is automatically adjusted to be a pointer to a pointer to an int"_ but, I am sorry to insist, I do not agree with @SouravGhosh : _"The former is an array of 2 int *s"_.  In prototype declaration : `void myfoo (int *ptr[2]) {
printf("%d \n",sizeof(ptr)); }` prints ptr size because it is ptr to ptr to int and in block declaration
`int main() {
int *ptr[2];
printf("%d \n",sizeof(ptr)); }` prints ptr size*2 because it is an array of 2 int*

Answer (score 1):

```
void myfoo (int array[]) { // No compilation error
;}
```

It means myfoo() will be called with an integer array (of any size). Compiler can just compile it.

```
void myfoo1 (int *array1) { // No compilation error
;}
```

It means myfoo1() will be called with a pointer to integer. Compiler can just compile it.

```
int main() {
    int array[]; // Compilation error
    int* array1; // No compilation error
}

int array[];
```

This is the definition of the array. But the compiler can not determine the size of the array. So it does not know how much memory to be allocated.
So you have to provide either size or initialize it with some values as below.

```
int array[3];
```

or

```
int array[] = {1,2,1};
```

.

```
int* array1;
```

This is just a declaration of integer pointer. Nothing wrong in it and compiler can compile it.

Comment: `void myfoo(int array[])` does not mean `myfoo` will be called with an integer array. In a function declaration, an array parameter is automatically adjusted to be a pointer. Thus `void myfoo(int array[])` becomes `void myfoo(int *array)`, and the array is called with a pointer to an `int`.